# Malliavin-Shavgulidze (type) measures on the group of measure-preserving invertible maps on $\mathbb T$?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, gr.group-theory, measure-theory, ds.dynamical-systems

The Malliavin-Shavgulidze measures on $\operatorname{Diff}^{1}(I)$ (with $I$ an interval of $\mathbb R$) are defined as the image $W_{\sigma} \circ f^{-1}$ of the Wiener measure $W_{\sigma}$ with variance $\sigma^{2}$ on $C_{0}(I)$ under the following homeomorphism $f$:
\begin{align*}
C_{0}(I) \ni B \mapsto f(B) \equiv\left[t \mapsto f(B)_{t}:=\int_{0}^{t} e^{B_{s}} d s / \int_{0}^{1} e^{B_{s}} d s\right] \in \operatorname{Diff}^{1}(I)
\end{align*}

A similar construction can be made on $\operatorname{Diff}^1(\mathbb T)$.

I refer to [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X06008742) for further references.

**Question**: What is a good analog of such measures on the group of measure-preserving invertible maps on $\mathbb T$?